# Test Rails nested form POST via terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, nested-forms

I have created nested form and want to test it from terminal. How can I Make POST request that creates 2 records - one for parent and one for child - at once?

Comment: I don't understand - if you are talking about an html form you want to test, I would suppose (if not writing specs) you would fire up a browser to test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/) can help. This is not "testing" but more "debugging" in terminal.

```
gem 'pry'
bundle install
```

and in the beginning of your action accepting post request, let's say create;

```
def create
  binding.pry
  ...
end
```

Browser will not respond but you will get what you want in your terminal.

See [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP-wise, nested forms are no different than regular forms. Rails uses the naming of the fields to separate parent data from child data. Use your browser's inspector to inspect the HTTP request sent when you fill out the form manually. From there, you can see the name of all the fields used. Then, in terminal, you can typically do something like this:

```bsh
curl --data "parent[foo]=1&child[bar]=2" http://myapp.dev/parent/create
```

Just replace the parent[foo] and similar with what you find in the inspector, and it should all work. Tail the dev log if you want to see potential errors in the request.

Answer (score -1):

How about to use rspec testing framework?

Comment: The question asks specifically how to do it in the terminal, which is perfectly reasonable in a lot of cases.

Comment: And I really don't understand why not to use normal and powerfull testing instead of handmade requests through console.